# Laravel 5 Multiple Insert in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am trying to multiple images insert with Laravel 5.1 using one controller method.

Here is my tried Code:

```
$images = Input::file('product_images');

foreach ($images as $image) {

    $productImage = new ProductImage();

    $filename = Input::get('imalatci_id') . '_product' . '_' . date('Y_m_d_H_i_s') . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(500, 400)->save('images/products/' . $filename);

    $productImage->product_id = $productId;
    $productImage->path = 'images/products/' . $filename;
    $productImage->save();

}
```

This code inserts single row to table.

How could gain multiple inserting?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `insert` function for add multiple records in one go.

```
foreach($images as $image){
$filename = Input::get('imalatci_id') . '_product' . '_' . date('Y_m_d_H_i_s') . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(500, 400)->save('images/products/' . $filename);
$image_arr[] = ['product_id'=>$productId,'path'=>'images/products/' . $filename ];    }
ProductImage::insert($image_arr);
```

but insert function does not update timestamps. You have to update that fields.